# Hosea 13:14 as quoted in 1 Corinthians 15

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches, 1-corinthians, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, hosea, esv

Hosea 13:14 reads in the ESV:

> Shall I ransom them from the power of Sheol?
>   Shall I redeem them from Death?
>   O Death, where are your plagues?
>   O Sheol, where is your sting?
>   Compassion is hidden from my eyes.

To my ears, this is a bewildering switching back and forth between judgment and deliverance all in a few phrases, because I am used to the middle phrases being used of Christ's triumph by Paul:

> When the perishable puts on the imperishable, and the mortal puts on immortality, then shall come to pass the saying that is written:
>   “Death is swallowed up in victory.”
>   “O death, where is your victory?
>   O death, where is your sting?” —1 Corinthians 15:54-55 (ESV)

- The implied answer to the first two ("shall") questions is "no," according to the phrasing of the ESV. Is this a good rendering?
- If so, what does this mean about the original sense of the next two questions? Are they a summoning of Death and Sheol rather than a triumphing over them?
- What hermeneutic is Paul applying to arrive at his use of these rhetorical questions? How is his use to be reconciled with the original context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you are getting at. In the ESV it does seem to speak just the way you say (my expanded paraphrase):

> Shall I save these wicked people from Sheol? (Of course not!)
>   Shall I redeem them from Death (Of course not!)
>
> ...But speaking of ‘redeem’ I will insert this confusing prophecy. For although I said ‘Of course not!' I will reject my people outwardly, but not those circumcised inwardly. My true people I will redeem by Messiah! Of course I will! Therefore, Messiah is a plague upon plagues and the death of death!

Interestingly, the Jewish historian [Alfred Edersheim](http://www.worthychristianlibrary.com/books/alfred-edersheim/the-life-and-times-of-jesus-the-messiah/), says in his appendix on Messianic texts that this verse was taken in reference to the Messiah:

> “Hos. xiii. 14 is applied to the deliverance by the Messiah of those of Israel
>   who are in Gehinnom, whom He sets free; - the term Zion being understood of
>   Paradise. See Yalk. on Is. Par. 269, comp. Maas. de R. Joshua in Jellinek’s Beth
>   ha-Midr. ii. p. 50.” (Ancient Rabbinic Source)

I think you found a gloss in some Bible translations as the ESV seems to capture the thought process better.

Answer (score 3):

> From the clutches of the grave I would ransom them, from death I would redeem them; I will be your words of death; I will decree the
>   grave upon you. Remorse shall be hidden from My eyes.

-[From the Complete Jewish Bible](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16167/showrashi/true)

> I will ransom them from the power of the grave; I will redeem them
>   from death: O death, I will be thy plagues; O grave, I will be thy
>   destruction: repentance shall be hid from mine eyes. - AV

These variations do not agree with the ESV that there is a question.  As for Paul, he is reading them as being completed in Christ. His is a commentary  rather than a quote.

Answer (score 0):

Paul is not quoting the Hebrew scriptures but rather the LXX (Greek version).

> 1 Corinthians 15:55 O death, **where [is] thy sting? O grave, where
>   [is] thy victory?**
>
> Brenton: Hosea 13:14 I will deliver them out of the power of Hades,
>   and will redeem them from death: **where is thy penalty, O death? O
>   Hades, where is thy sting?** comfort is hidden from mine eyes.
>
> Masoretic (KJV): Hosea 13:14 I will ransom them from the
>   power of the grave; I will redeem them from death: **O death, I will be
>   thy plagues; O grave, I will be thy destruction**: repentance shall be
>   hid from mine eyes.

Clearly Paul is referring to the LXX and not a Hebrew source.

The NET Bible has this excellent rendering of the Hebrew version:

> NET ©  Will I deliver them from the power of Sheol? No, I will not! 1 
>   Will I redeem them from death? No, I will not! O Death, bring on your
>   plagues! 2  O Sheol, bring on your destruction! 3  My eyes will not
>   show any compassion!

The sense is completely opposite from Paul's celebratory interpretation.

NOTE: I should point out that Paul is NOT speaking of "resurrection" here. Instead he is saying that when those who "are alive and remain" get caught up *without ever dying* then will come to pass the thwarting of death.

Had Paul been looking at a Hebrew text he would not have seen it as a positive thing.

Comment: Peshitta Hosea renders "victory" instead of "plagues", matching Paul's quote. I don't think Paul was misquoting or spinning anything, or even quoting the LXX, which appears to have corrupted this passage.